# Consulta entre duas tabelas sqlite

Tags: sqlite

Minha dúvida é como fazer uma consulta entre duas tabelas.

Seria uma tabela  `Pedidos` com o  campo `Idprod`, `idCliente`.

A outra seria a tabela de `Produtos` com os campos `Idprod`, `Descricao`.

Eu queria fazer uma pesquisa de `Produtos` comprados pelo determinado cliente.

Estou usando visual studio 2015 xamarin forms, banco de dados `sqlite`.

**Já tentei assim mas não deu certo:**

```
Select Idprod,Descricao From Produtos INNER JOIN pedidos on Produtos.Idprod = pedidos.Idprod
```

Comment: A sua estrutura só tem um produto por pedido? Quando vc diz que não deu certo, o que significa? Deu erro? Seria interessante colocar na pergunta exemplos de dados e resultados que você obteve e resultado que você esperava obter.

Answer (score 1):

Não sei como está definida a sua regra de negócio, mas analisando de forma superficial acredito que esteja incorreta.

A relação de `pedido` é de `1...N`, você deveria ter uma entidade `pedido_produto` onde é efetuado o relacionamento entre pedidos e produtos.

**tabela_pedido**

```
+----+------------+
| id | cliente_id |
+----+------------+
|  1 |          2 |
|  2 |          3 |
|  3 |          1 |
+----+------------+
```

**tabela_produto**

```
+----+------------+
| id | descricao  |
+----+------------+
|  1 | SMART TV   |
|  2 | NOTEBOOK   |
|  3 | SMARTPHONE |
+----+------------+
```

**tabela_pedido_produto**

```
+-----------+------------+
| pedido_id | produto_id |
+-----------+------------+
|         1 |          2 |
|         1 |          3 |
|         2 |          1 |
|         2 |          3 |
|         3 |          1 |
+-----------+------------+
```

Com o seguinte `DDL`:

```
CREATE TABLE tabela_cliente (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,
    nome VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE tabela_pedido (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,
    cliente_id INT
);

CREATE TABLE tabela_produto (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY key,
    descricao VARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TABLE tabela_pedido_produto (
    pedido_id INT,
    produto_id INT,
);

INSERT INTO tabela_cliente (nome) VALUES
('João'),
('José'),
('Maria'),
('Madalena');

INSERT INTO tabela_pedido (cliente_id) VALUES
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4);

INSERT INTO tabela_produto (descricao) VALUES
('SMARTPHONE'),
('SMARTV'),
('NOTEBOOK');


INSERT INTO tabela_pedido_produto (pedido_id, produto_id) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(2, 2),
(2, 3),
(3, 1),
(4, 2);
```

Você selecionaria os pedidos relacionando os clientes e produtos:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tabela_pedido p
LEFT JOIN tabela_cliente c ON c.id = p.cliente_id
LEFT JOIN tabela_pedido_produto pp ON pp.pedido_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN tabela_produto pr ON pr.id = pp.produto_id
```

Se por exemplo, você quiser obter os pedidos e produtos do cliente **João**, basta adicionar a cláusula `WHERE`:

```
WHERE p.cliente_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá @Eloi,

Tenta assim:

```
Select Produtos.Idprod
     , Produtos.Descricao 
  From Produtos INNER JOIN Pedidos on Produtos.Idprod = Pedidos.Idprod
 Where Pedidos.IdCliente = 'id do cliente'
```

Do jeito que você escreveu vai dar erro de ambiguidade, tanto a tabela `Produtos` quanto a tabela `Pedidos` possuem a coluna `Idprod`, então você precisa deixar explícito no select a qual tabela pertence a coluna, `Produtos.Idprod` ou `Pedidos.Idprod`.

[]s

---

Eloi eu preciso desses detalhes no quadrado vermelho pra entender o que acontece, quanto mais informações você fornecer sobre o erro melhor:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Felipe, fiz como vc sugeriu. fiz no Sqlite Explorer ai funcionou direitinho, mas quando eu tento no meu projeto não funciona. estou usando o visual studio 2015 , aplicativo multiplataformas (Xamarin forms) meu código esta em uma classe: public List<Produtos> Listaprod(Pedidos pedidos)  {   return cn.Query<Produtos> ("    Select Produtos.Idprod
     , Produtos.Descricao 
  From Produtos INNER JOIN Pedidos on Produtos.Idprod = Pedidos.Idprod"); }

Comment: Entendi...nesse caso eu preciso que você me explique o que acontece, lança um erro? Retorna uma lista vazia?

Comment: sim lança um erro, abre um messagem  " Na unhandled exception occured. " como opção de interromper ou continuar, quando eu escolho continuar o aplicativo encerra.

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo do que eu preciso sobre os erros na resposta